# Page header shows correctly in Mozilla but not Chrome and IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla

The header of my page is displaying properly in Mozilla but not in IE and Chrome. In Mozilla, the logo (which I have blocked out for privacy) and the signup form are in the center and the right size. However, in IE and Chrome, the logo is a lot smaller and the logo and signup form are further to the left and closer to the top.

Here are links to the Mozilla version and Chrome version:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHDn4.jpg (Mozilla)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5suFY.jpg (Chrome)

Here is the code for it. I didn't use any css.

```
<div id="logo_slide" style="margin-left: 41.2%; margin-right: 41.2%; width: 19.53%;">
<a href="http://www.insertwebsite.com/image.png">
<img src="http://www.insertwebsite.com/image.png" 
alt="website 200 200" width="200" height="208" class="alignnone 
size-full wp-image-245" /></a></div>

<div id="mc_embed_signup" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 5%; 
width: 500px;"><h2 class="validate"><span style="color: #eb583b;">
Enter your email to stay tuned</span></h2>
<div class="mc-field-group" style="text-align: left;"><input id="mce-EMAIL"     
class="required email" style="width: 250px;" name="EMAIL" type="email" value="" /></div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear" style="text-align: left;"></div>
<p style="text-align: left;">
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups--></p>

<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; text-align: left;">
<input name="b_170e723679933c7b075b72016_d3458b5f5a" type="text" value="" /></div>
<div class="clear" style="text-align: left;">
<input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" name="subscribe" type="submit" 
value="Go" /></div>
```

Comment: I made this fiddle for your code, with the logo in red to make it visible - http://jsfiddle.net/6f8xf1u5/ I have looked in FF and IE but I think that it looks better in IE than FF. Can you please add some more information about your problem as at the moment I feel it is a little unclear. If you can't add an image, upload one to a free image hosting service like imgur.com and include a link to it in your post.

Comment: I have updated it with links. The problem is that the positioning of the logo and signup form are in the center where they should be for Mozilla but that is not the case for Chrome and IE.